# I want to make UI such as the select box + text box

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Nice to meet you. I developed Windows application with VisualStudio so far. 
It was these days and has begun to do the Web application.

Therefore there is a question, but will there be UI which added a select box and text box in HTML?

Though it can choose some choices, it is a thing to have the direct input if there does not have it. 
It is the guy who seems to be the URL input area of a place saying in FireFox and IE. 
A past history appears here with a list like a select box and can input it directly.

When there was such a demand, how should it have been settled? 
Will it be a feeling to arrange a select box and text box?

Comment: Ahh... you used Babelfish to translate to English from What language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using ASP.NET Ajax check out the AJAX Control Toolkit ("ACT"), it has a ComboBox control.  Very easy to use and a [demo online here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to learn about are [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx); these are custom components wherein you can combine standard ASP.NET controls in one component and use them for your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a ComboBox control, but is this for ASP.Net or Winforms?